# iTunes scripting with Scripting Bridge & Sandboxing

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, itunes, appstore-sandbox

I have an app which tells iTunes to play music using the ScriptingBridge framework. The app either tells iTunes to play a playlist or a certain track. The app is also sandboxed.

To play a playlist, here's what I have:

```
iTunesPlaylist* playlist = ...
[playlist playOnce: YES];
```

To play a track, it's pretty straightforward as well:

```
iTunesTrack* track = ...
[track playOnce: YES];
```

Since my app is sandboxed, I have the following lines in my entitlements file:

```
<key>com.apple.security.scripting-targets</key>
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.iTunes</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.iTunes.library.read</string> // I also have this to read the playlists/tracks the user has on his library
        <string>com.apple.iTunes.playback</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

I have tested without app sandboxing and the code works perfectly. With sandboxing though the playlist code works fine, but playing a track does *not* work. I checked with the Console app and nothing seems to be logged that concerns sandboxd and my app.

At first I thought that I might be missing some `access-group` in my entitlements file, but then I thought that wouldn't make sense because I already have the `playback` one. And I couldn't find any list of access groups for iTunes on the net (I even tried using sdef to get a property list from iTunes and search for 'access-group' but found nothing - it's not there) so I couldn't confirm if I needed any more.

To sum up, why is sandbox preventing this from working?

Comment: Are u sure your app will submitted by Apple?

Comment: @NikolaiNagorny what do you mean? I'm the one submitting my app to the MAS

Comment: i want to use Scripting Bridge but i uncertain that Apple submit my app with this technology...

Comment: @NikolaiNagorny I haven't found one source that states that Apple will not accepted an app which uses Scripting Bridge (including the [Mac App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/mac/resources/approval/guidelines.html))

Comment: @Alex Do you know what needs to be added to the entitlements file to be able to add a playlists, and then tracks to that playlist?  I've tried com.apple.iTunes.library.write, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: @Alex I put a question here if you want to get some points for answering! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875345/creating-playlists-in-itunes-using-scripting-bridge-in-a-sandboxed-app

Comment: @Alex Just to get an update, was your app accepted by apple appstore ? I am doing something similar

Comment: @Alex Are you able to access iTunesTrack location path ? not working for me on 10.8 with entitlement of accessing music read any ideas ?

Comment: @Ahmed Yes, my app had no problem in getting accepted by Apple. Regarding iTunesTrack location, I'm afraid I can't help you there since I never tried accessing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. It turns out I was calling `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` on an `SBElementArray` to find out the track I wanted to play and that *somehow* was messing things up. Now I use the method `objectWithName:` and it works.